# How to hide tilebar in compact overlay mode in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, titlebar

my app requires a very simple UI with just a textblock and image(basically with no interactive elements).
So I used following code in App.xaml.cs on App launched and app activated methods.

```
        private void SetupTitleBar()
        {
            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

            var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        }
```

And this is my simple titelbar component in MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="TitleBar" MinHeight="32" Background="{ThemeResource TitleBarAcrylicBackgroundBrush}" Grid.row =0 VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Height="16" Width="16" Margin="16,8,12,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="../Assets/AppLogo.png" />
                <TextBlock 
                x:Name="AppNameTextBlock"
                Margin="44,8,0,8"
                Text="AppName"
                FontSize="12"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs, I have

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Window.Current.SetTitleBar(TitleBar)   
}
```

In normal mode everything works fine. When I switch to compact overlay mode on clicking some button, requirement is to not show the titlebar. **Hence in compact overlay mode, I cannot drag the app using cursor** as I set the visibility of TitleBar grid false and that is understandable since UI element that I set as tilebar is not visible.

And on removing the line *Window.Current.SetTitleBar(TitleBar)* **the search button in main page come to top left corner of app is not clickable sometimes.**

I tried multiple things of setting titlebars from docs but nothings seems to work. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the 'Important' note about the dragable region. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui2#title-bar-content-and-drag-regions

Comment: **My Idea:** I thought of adding a <`Grid x:Name="MainTitleBar" Background="Transparent"/>` in MainPage.xaml that looks like invisible which I'll use as Window.Current.SetTitleBar(MainTitleBar). As this titlebar is visible always in normal and compact overlay mode, I can drag the app in any mode and can use interactive elements anywhere. And in that titlebar grid with app name and logo visibility is set only in normal mode.

Comment: But I couldn't figure out how to set the grid as invisible component. Though I use background as transparent, it shows the mica color effect.

Comment: You cannot set Visibility to false, you can set it collapsed, it's not the same.

Comment: In UWP, there are only two states of visibility. Visible or Collapsed. There is no hidden state as in WPF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility?view=winrt-22621

Comment: You should keep the grid visible and collapse the inner controls

Answer (score 0):

In UWP applications, the title bar is an integral part of the window and cannot be hidden completely in compact overlay mode. However, you can make the title bar less visible by customizing its appearance to match the background color or by reducing its height.

To customize the title bar in compact overlay mode, you can use the `CoreApplicationViewTitleBar` class. Here's an example of how you can minimize the visibility of the title bar.

```
    // Get the CoreApplicationViewTitleBar
CoreApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;

    // Set the title bar colors.

    titleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar viewTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    viewTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    viewTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

    // Reduce the height of the title bar
    viewTitleBar.Height = 20;` // Set the desired height

    // Set the title bar to an accent color (optional)

    titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.YourDesiredColor;
    titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.YourDesiredColor;
```

By setting ExtendViewIntoTitleBar to true, the content of your application will extend into the title bar area. You can then set the ButtonBackgroundColor and ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor properties to Colors.Transparent to make the buttons blend with the title bar. Additionally, you can reduce the height of the title bar by setting the Height property of ApplicationViewTitleBar.

Please note that although you can customize the appearance of the title bar, it is not possible to completely hide it in compact overlay mode in UWP applications. The title bar will still be visible to some extent.